# Eclipse BIRT view report button not working

Tags: eclipse, birt

I saw lot of posts for this issue mentioned below.Either the proposed solution in the other websites are not working or some of the internet links are not working.
Do you have a concrete solution for this issue,I would like to know please?

```
 HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /viewer/frameset. Reason:

Server Error

Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but the answer is depending on your BIRT version.
I am using 4.2.1 for development. This requires JRE 6 (no more, no less) for viewing. You can specifiy the VM on the command line or in eclipse.ini.

Comment: I succeeded by downloading RCP designer for BIRT.Its very simple and It has all functionalities of BIRT.http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/